# Hover em thumbnail alterar imagem em div maior

Tags: html, css

Tenho 2 div, uma **div menor** que em que ficam as thumbnail (imagens pequenas) e outra **div maior**, que após o efeito hover quero que aumente o tamanho da imagem nessa div e sobreponha o texto que está nela, exemplo:

Sem o hover:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Durante o hover( Ao passar o mouse que a imagem no thumbnail fique maior na div maior):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Olá amigo! fiz um [**jsffidle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/1rry3ssm/2/) de exemplo, se for isso mesmo me fale que posto como resposta .. =]

Comment: Perfeito, amigo, só que a thumbnail fica ativa e a imagem não "fecha", gostaria que fosse no efeito de :hover ou até com um botão para fechar a imagem e continuar lendo o texto, novamente, obrigado!

Comment: Olá, dessa forma que fiz não vamos conseguir implementar no hover :/ porque trabalho com checkbox para exibir as imagens. mais nem tudo está perdido hehe, da para fazer conforme você falou acima de ter uma opção para sumir com a imagem =] olha esse [**jsffidle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/1rry3ssm/5/).